# Reconstruction failed Error with HelloPhotogrammetry

Tags: swift, xcode, photogrammetry, usdz, xcode13

I'm trying to create a USDZ object with the tutorial from Apple
[Creating 3D Objects from Photographs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_3d_objects_from_photographs). I'm using the new [PhotogrammetrySession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/photogrammetrysession) within this sample project: [Photogrammetry Command-Line App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_a_photogrammetry_command-line_app).

That's the code:

```
let inputFolderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/MyInputImages/")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "MyObject.usdz")
var request = PhotogrammetrySession.Request.modelFile(url: url, 
                                                      detail: .full)
guard let session = try PhotogrammetrySession(input: inputFolderUrl) else {
    return      }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
2021-06-12 21:53:56.968490+0200 HelloPhotogrammetry[15294:190841] ERROR cv3dapi.pg: Internal codes (1): 4011
2021-06-12 21:53:56.972113+0200 HelloPhotogrammetry[15294:190841] [Photogrammetry] No SfM map found in native output!
2021-06-12 21:53:56.972909+0200 HelloPhotogrammetry[15294:190841] [Photogrammetry] Got error in completion: reconstructionFailed(RealityFoundation.PhotogrammetrySession.Request.modelFile(url: OutputAR.usdz -- file:///Users/jonasdeichelmann/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloPhotogrammetry-ghttmmgcrrhywqeebbrstrvxoikh/Build/Products/Debug/, detail: RealityFoundation.PhotogrammetrySession.Request.Detail.medium, geometry: nil), "Reconstruction failed!")
Request modelFile(url: OutputAR.usdz -- file:///Users/jonasdeichelmann/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloPhotogrammetry-ghttmmgcrrhywqeebbrstrvxoikh/Build/Products/Debug/, detail: RealityFoundation.PhotogrammetrySession.Request.Detail.medium, geometry: nil) had an error: reconstructionFailed("Reconstruction failed!")
Processing is complete!
```

I'm using an M1 iMac with macOS Monterey 12.0 Beta (21A5248p) and Xcode 13.0 beta (13A5154h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Try another set of images, probably there is something wrong with your set of images.

I've had it work successfully except in one instance, and I received the same error that you are getting. I think for some reason it didn't like the set of photos I took for that particular object. You could try taking just a few photos of another simple object and try again and see if that is the problem with your first run.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that was the problem. After I did another photo-shot it worked. Unfortunately the, error doesn't tell you what's wrong with the Images.